# Creating an Array from a text file with more than one data type in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create an array from a text file with both numbers and letters (as a header), however when I try to convert and open my file I end up getting the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0

or

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: AA

I understand that this is a data type problem and was wondering if anyone knew a way around this? I'm new to python and usually code in Matlab. my text file consists of:

```
AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

and the code I have tried is below

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
print
```

After that, I need to cut all the columns that have zeroes and keep the ones that have 1s in them. The text files to be loaded in will be different each time and I only need to see which cells and headers have been populated with a 1.

Comment: what is exactly in your file? alternate lines of numbers, letters. or only single line of letters with next line of numbers.

Comment: If you are going to have mixed text and numbers, forcing you to use `dtype=object` then you probably don't want a numpy array but rather a regular Python list.

Comment: its one line of letters with a line of numbers below it.
thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga! Would the format of putting it into a python list be similar?

Comment: What do you get when you load that in MATLAB?

Comment: Is the letter line column headers or data?  What do you need to do with this data once loaded?

Comment: The text line has 7 columns, the number on 9.  `loadtxt` isn't going to like that.

Comment: @hpaulj The letter line is a header and yeah I messed up. I fixed that so the number of columns are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) allows a dtype parameter, something like this will read mixed data:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt('test.txt', dtype=object)
```

#### How should I solve this?

So, now that we have answered the how do I make `numpy.readtxt()` read my file, let's go with how I would solve the problem of analyzing the zeros and ones in the file.  The following code snippets read in the file, and then find which columns contain any ones, and all ones.

**1: Use the csv module**

The [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module can be used to parse this file.

```
import csv
with open('file1', 'rU') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # read the first line as the header
    header = [c.strip() for c in next(csv_reader)]

    # read the remaining lines, and transpose them into columns using zip()
    cols = list(zip(*((int(c) for c in l) for l in csv_reader)))

# now lets find all the columns which have any and all ones
any_ones = [l for l, v in zip(header, cols) if any(v)]
all_ones = [l for l, v in zip(header, cols) if all(v)]

print(any_ones)
print(all_ones)
```

**2: Use pandas**

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) can also be used to do this work.  More learning curve than the above, but you get what you pay for.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1')
# remove spaces from column names
df = df.rename(columns={x: x.strip() for x in df.columns})

any_ix = df.any()
all_ix = df.all()

print(list(any_ix[any_ix].index))
print(list(any_ix[all_ix].index))
```

**Results of csv and pandas**

```
['AB', 'AD', 'AE', 'AG']
['AB', 'AE']
```

**File1:**

```
AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

Comment: Do we really want to inflict object dtype arrays on a new python coder?

Comment: @hpaulj, you have a point, I would normally not offer up `numpy.readtxt()` as a solution to his problem, except that he asked a specific question about typing and had already picked up the `numpy` knife.  So I showed him where the sharp end was.

Comment: I am open to using something besides numpy!

Comment: If that is the case, best thing you can do to get more specific answers it to answer @hpaulj question above which is: *What do you need to do with this data once loaded?*

Comment: Once the data is loaded I need to cut all the columns that have zeroes and keep the ones that have 1s in them. The text files to be loaded in will be different each time and i only need to see which cells and headers have been populated with a 1,

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your file is called `file.text` and inside there is:

```
AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG

0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

You can read the file with:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_file = f.read()
```

Create list from string (that is what `read_file` is now):

```
list_entries = read_file.split(',')
```

Print every entry in the list (replace `\n` new line character):

```
for entry in list_entries:
    print entry.replace('\n', '')
```